# windows defender "device disabled"

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I'm using windows 10 with symantec endpoint, in the last week the defender suddenly started to "pop up" with the alert that the device is disabled and that there are issues with the symantec EP.
this happens when i try to use an Internet Explorer based program, which i use to remotely control a computer.
In the control-panel the defender shows that it is disabled.

The symantec EP is "all green", no errors or alerts.

When the alert starts, i must restart the computer - otherwise it takes the focus every 5 seconds.

Comment: what does it prompt? Endpoint Protection No Longer Disables Windows Defender On Some Windows 10 Computers 
 https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH247503.html

Comment: that's the issue, it prompts a general "there is an issue" alert. the front page of the defender.

Comment: To determine if there is compatibility issue between two antivirus software, you can uninstall Symantec temporary, checking if it will prompt when you remote control other pc.

Comment: Difficult to diagnose an issue if you don’t specify which version of EndPoint you are using.  You also failed to provide adequate infrastructure about your Windows 10 installation.  Windows Defender compatibly has been improved in the newer builds of Windows 10.  So which build are you using?